# How To Create CheckBox in Dropdownlist in asp.net with code pls no links

Tags: asp.net

I Want to implement the Checkbox in DropDownlist using only c# code and if possible i want to use this checkbox in dropdownlist as userControl Please Help Me guys.

Comment: You can't. You will have to create a `<div>` that behaves as a DropDown.

Comment: How To do that?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Try it yourself first by using Google or the Search box on the top-right. If you still have problems after that we can help you further.

Comment: You can use jquery library for this. eg. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect/

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple checkbox inside dropdown using jQuery Bootstrap Multi-Select Plugin like

In order to implement a Multiple Select (MultiSelect) DropDownList with CheckBoxes in ASP.Net we will need to make use of ListBox control and apply the jQuery Bootstrap Multi-Select Plugin to it.

Download Bootstrap and jQuery Bootstrap Multi-Select Plugin
The download locations are as follows.
Bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/

jQuery BootStrap Multi-Select Plugin
You will need to download the plugin files from the following location.
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/
The complete documentation can be read on the following page.
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

**HTML Markup** -
The HTML Markup consists of an ASP.Net ListBox and a Button control.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

**Applying the jQuery Bootstrap Multi-Select Plugin to the ListBox control**
The very first thing you will need to do is to inherit the following JavaScript and CSS files.
1. jQuery JS file
2. Bootstrap JavaScript and CSS files.
3. jQuery BootStrap Multi-Select Plugin JavaScript and CSS files.
Once all the files are inherited then we need to simply apply the plugin to the ListBox inside the jQuery document ready event handler.

**The plugin supports various options, here I am making use of includeSelectAllOption which adds a Select all CheckBox when specified and set to True.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>


protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    foreach (ListItem item in lstFruits.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            message += item.Text + " " + item.Value + "\\n";
        }
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

[image]

For full source code go through this link [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)

Comment: Can I load the list items dinamicaly from DataTable?